# Fine tuning of Image-Charts radar diagram

Tags: image-charts

I have the following radar chart diagram from [www.image-charts.com](http://www.image-charts.com):

[image]

You can open the chart's parameters in their online editor using [this](https://editor.image-charts.com/#https://image-charts.com/chart?chco=0073CF%2CAAAAAA&chd=t%3A50%2C56%2C100%2C23%2C62%2C81%2C50%2C50%2C50%7C49%2C73%2C100%2C30%2C66%2C73%2C78%2C62%2C49&chg=0%2C0%2C1%2C10&chl=WT%7CBP%7CGF%7CNV%7CZL%7CSL%7CAR%7CZB&chlps=color%2CFF00FF%7Cfont.size%2C25&chm=B%2C0073CFBB%2C0%2C0%2C0%7CB%2CAAAAAABB%2C1%2C0%2C0&chof=.png&chs=547x547&cht=r&chxr=0%2C0%2C100%2C1000) link.

Is it possible to change the font size and the color of the axis labels (e.g. "WT", "ZB" etc.)? If so, how can I do it? I cannot find the parameter which is responsible the styling of those labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly it's currently not possible through the `/chart` API.

However you can use the new [Image Charts /chart.js API endpoint](https://documentation.image-charts.com/chart.js/) to leverage the whole [Chart.js configuration object](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/).